# Add New Filter functionality in C# projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In *C++* projects in *Visual Studio 2008* there is possibility to **Add -> New filter** which will be usefull if one wants to separate some files from others (ie. source files from header files) and keep each type in "semifolders" without moving them physically on the hard disk. I wanted to do the same in *c#* projects with, lets say xml files, but the only option here is to create folder physically, which I want to avoid. And there are my questions:

1. Is it possible (and how) to create filters in *C#* projects?
2. Why *C#* and *C++* project's **Add** options differ from each other (in first you can add folder(not filter) and in second filter(not folder)?

ps. I am using *VS2008* and I don't know if this changed in *VS2010*.

Comment: From this what I have searched and what Adkins also wrote it is not possible to have filters like functionality in C#. Registered User mentioned the VSCommands tool and although it is very useful it is not the same as filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to create filters for use in C# projects.  The projects in C# are organized with the use of actual folders on your hard drive. Sorry. As for why C# and C++ have different options, well that is simply because they are different languages.  C# is a more high level language then C++ so (I am only guessing) they went with folders to make it more visible what is going on in the project.

Comment: I think the real reason is they were developed by different teams in Microsoft, with different opinions and no desire to compromise.

Comment: 8 years later, and I cannot believe there's still no filter option.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can group files together:

[image]

To do that you will need to install free extension [VSCommands 2010](http://vscommands.com/download) or [VSCommands 2008](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/E93945C9-96E8-4A0D-BCC3-BD40BF799773)

Answer (score 0):

sadly: No 'Filters' - in `MSBUILD` that C# Projects use.

Possible work-around is to have a real Folder that contains symbolic links to the handpicked files you seek to group.