# How to group source files in VS2013 not using folders on disk

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, csproj

Older VS (using C++) allowed (as far as I can remember) grouping of related sources to sort of groups. Something like Headers group, Sources group etc.

Is it possible to group files in such way in VS2013 using C#? Even if it does mean manual edit of the project xml files.

The only way I have found is to create a Folder, but the requirement is to have flat structure on disk and tree structure in project.

Edit:
It is called Filter in the C++ projects.
And it seems impossible for C# as [already discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666360/add-new-filter-functionality-in-c-sharp-projects).

Comment: Folders only give the *effect* of hierarchical structure in Visual Studio - they actually have a flat structure on disc.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not apply for C# project: Using Add/New Folder the VS adds a folder named NewFolder1 and also creates this directory in the source tree. If you delete such directory it claims the folder has been deleter or moved etc :o(

Answer (score 1):

I think the only Folder that matches is the Solution Folder, but you cannot use it inside a Project, only in solution Level.

You can group files or Projects in it.

> Solution -> Add -> New Solution Folder